# Creating an object from this data

Tags: php, object

I have the following code which takes the data in a variable `$main` and loops through it so that it outputs the markup below

```
Form1

Firstname
    Stack
Lastname
    Overflow

Form2

Grade
    some grade
Address
    some address
School
    some school
```

The code I use to loop through `$main` is this, and it outputs markup, as you can see dl,dd,dt, etc. How can I create an object instead that could be traversed as `$main_object->form1->firstname` or something like that?

```
foreach ($main as $info){
   foreach ($info as $form => $data){

      $output .= '<h4>'. ucfirst($form) .'</h4>';               
      $output .= '<dl>';
      foreach ($data as $key => $value){
          $output .= '<dt>'. ucfirst($key) .'</dt>';
      if (is_array($value)){
             foreach ($value as $label => $val){
                $output .= '<dd>'. $val .'</dd>';
             }
          } else {
             $output .= '<dd>'. $value .'</dd>';
          }
      }
      $output .= '</dl>';

   }//foreach
}//foreach
```

Comment: How does one determine what is a header and what is a value? Will you have multiple forms (`Form2`, `Form3`, etc.)?

Comment: @Tim Cooper Yes, this is what `foreach ($info as $form => $data){` is for. It loops through the forms. I'm hoping someone could tell me the object syntax just from translating the current markup syntax I'm not sure hwo to create an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects can be created by instantiating a new `stdClass` instance. You should be able to modify the following example to suit your needs:

```
$root = new stdClass;

// For each form

   $current_form = $root->$form_name = new stdClass;

   // For each item

      $current_form->$item_name = $item_value;
```

A dump of the object will then yield something like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Form1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Firstname] => Stack
            // etc..
        )

)
```

Which can then be accessed via:

```
$root->Form1->Firstname;
```